# cordova error: Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I have a ionic project. It was successfully build and run in my android phone. suddenly from someday, when I run command "ionic cordova run android" I get the build error as below:

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:775)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:741)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:88)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1683)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:695)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:592)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:321)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:292)
        at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:54)
        at com.android.builder.core.DexByteCodeConverter.lambda$dexInProcess$0(DexByteCodeConverter.java:173)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:476)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:787)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:88)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1722)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:773)
        ... 16 more

1 error; aborting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx256M
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I have tried "cordova clean", but it doesn't work.

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version **52** byte code corresponds to Java 8, you need to add below to your `app/build.gradle` to make your project be compatible with Java 8.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: New error: BUILD FAILED
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Total time: 5.83 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

Comment: Still error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException

Comment: Your android gradle plugin version is?

Comment: gradleVersion = '2.14.1'

Comment: Try to upgrade to 3+?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue building with Cordova-Android 6.3.0

Removing the android platform and re-adding with 6.4.0 resolved the issue for me.