# Cordova: Android build is failing Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, gradle, build

Getting this while creating the android build from cordova

```
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
```

gradle file is autogenerated in cordova, so don't know where to add this.
Using angularjs with cordova.

Tried changing the classpath, which says to change the dustributionURL and when you change the distributionUrl, it get changed whiile doing another build.

Comment: This thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624243/8034839 may be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cordova error: Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623953/cordova-error-dex-error-converting-bytecode-to-dex-cause-dex-cannot-parse-ve)